# Console command to repair missing limbs from resurrected NPCs

Tags: pc, fallout-4

When resurrecting an NPC using the console command 'resurrect', is there any known method to restore/repair missing limbs?  For example, an NPC that had his arm and head blown off can be resurrected, but will walk around without a head or arm anymore, even though they seem fully functional still.  I'd like to know if there's a discovered method for fixing this.

Comment: Ive added the pc tag. Inmost cases, we do not use a platform tag with a game. This is because the question could apply to the other platforms, and be just as helpful to someone playing on xbox or playstation. In this case, you are asking for a PC only solution to an issue that rises from a PC only mechanic. In cases like these, platform tags are appropriate.

Comment: Okay.  That's fine, although none of the other console questions for Fallout 4 are tagged that way [ source: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bfallout-4%5D+console ], but I'm fine with the edit.  PS4 is supposed to be getting mods and console access at some point, at which time this question may not be relevant exclusively to PC users, too.  Something to consider.

Comment: Eh. They probably should be. Generally, console tags are infamous for being used improperly, which is why I make the effort to comment with why Ive made the change. If and when console gets added to.. consoles.. this should definetly be changed.

Comment: I don't think you can fix those, I kind of remember being able to ressurect NPC's/Companions in Skyrim, but they wouldn't get there slashed off limbs back.

Comment: Aw, man... this is one of those questions that would have rocketed to the top of the hot questions list with a better title, like "After you've brought somebody back from the dead, how do you put their limbs back on?"

Comment: @T.J.L.: I think the title is quite awesome as it is, at least I came here because of the title ^^

Answer (score 1):

If you ~disable and ~enable them (after clicking on them), they will respawn. Be warned that this seems to reset and randomize their inventory, so take what you want from them first.